# Front controller reached 100 router match iterations when run this www.baseurl.com/home/feed url

Tags: magento

I am facing magento url error **Front controller reached 100 router match iterations** when run this `www.baseurl.com/home/feed url`. please help me resolve this issue.

Comment: include router's match function code in your question, and also read alan storm articles, http://alanstorm.com/category/magento#dispatch

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://tutorialmagento.com/fixing-front-controller-reached-100-router-match-iterations)  is a way to find out the exact issue
Open the file

```
app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php
```

and find the code segment

```
while (!$request->isDispatched() && $i++<100) {
    foreach ($this->_routers as $router) {
        if ($router->match($this->getRequest())) {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

replace it with

```
Mage::log('----Matching routers------------------------------');
Mage::log('Total ' . count($this->_routers) . ': ' . implode(', ', array_keys($this->_routers)));
while (!$request->isDispatched() && $i++<100) {
    Mage::log('- Iteration ' . $i);
    $requestData = array(
        'path_info' => $request->getPathInfo(),
        'module' => $request->getModuleName(),
        'action' => $request->getActionName(),
        'controller' => $request->getControllerName(),
        'controller_module' => $request->getControllerModule(),
        'route' => $request->getRouteName()
    );

    $st = '';
    foreach ($requestData as $key => $val) {
        $st .= "[{$key}={$val}]";
    }
    Mage::log('Request: ' . $st);
    foreach ($this->_routers as $name => $router) {
        if ($router->match($this->getRequest())) {
            Mage::log('Matched by "' . $name . '" router, class ' . get_class($router));
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Reload your site again and you can see the detailed error log at `var/log/system.log`